# How to verify entered password from the database in codeIginitor 4 login form

Tags: php, authentication, codeigniter-4

I'm new to codeignitor and i've been struggling to verify the entered password with the one from the database I think I am missing something here.
The code below is extended from authentication controller and login function.

```
        if(!$this->validate($rules, $errors)){
            $data['validation'] = $this->validator;
            //$data['title_meta'] = view('partials/title-meta', ['title' => 'Login']);              
        } else{
            // Get Login Form data
            $email = $this->request->getVar('useremail');
            $password = $this->request->getVar('password');
            $model = new UserModel();
            $user = $model->where('email', $email)->first();
            
            
           if($user){
                
                $pass = $user['password'];
                $verify_pass = password_verify($password, $pass);
                
                if($verify_pass){
                    $data= [
                    'id' => $user['id'],
                    'email' => $user['email'],
                    'username' => $user['username'],
                    'isLoggedIn' => true
                ];
                session()->set($data);
                return redirect()->to('home');
                }else {
                    session()->setFlashdata('fail', 'Incorrect Password');
                    return redirect()->to('auth-login')->withInput();
                }
            }
            
                            
        }
        return view('auth-login', $data);
    }
```

Comment: What is not working? What is the expected output/behavior? Are you getting any errors? [ask]

Comment: The login password is not matching with the password from the database